# Why DOESN’T Kotlin smart cast work, even when both are `val`s

Tags: kotlin

In the below code, both the variables are `val`s, but the smart cast doesn't work even after the null check. Why?

```kotlin
fun SLLNode?.sumListWith(node: SLLNode?, carry: Int = 0): SLLNode? =
    when {
        this == null && node == null -> if (carry == 0) null else SLLNode(carry)
        this == null -> node.also { it!!.value += carry } // Smart cast doesn't work here.
        node == null -> this.also { value += carry } // Works here.
        else -> {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, just because smart-cast wasn't smart enough in this particular case

Comment: This code works fine, can you please elaborate on what result are you expecting?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10461

Comment: In when expression (line no.4 in the code), I expect not to use double bang, smart cast should be able to figure out that `node` is not null @mightyWOZ

Comment: you could write `node?.also { it.value += carry }` if you hate the `!!` operator (which should be used rarely), there is no other option except waiting for the bug fix

Comment: But why can't the compiler derive that `node` cannot be null, based on the above null check and current check of this? @TienDoNam

Comment: It doesn't _try_ to derive this in general, I believe because it couldn't always get it right and behavior could be unpredictable. Instead it checks for a few specific cases and this doesn't happen to be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Smart cast is working!, just make sure that `value` property is `var` in class SLLNode:

```
class SLLNode(var value: Int)  // Not val

fun SLLNode?.sumListWith(node: SLLNode?, carry: Int = 0): SLLNode? =
    when {
        this == null && node == null -> if (carry == 0) null else SLLNode(carry)
        this == null -> node.also { it!!.value += carry } // Smart cast doesn't work here.
        node == null -> this.also { value += carry } // Works here.
        else -> {
            ...
        }
    }
```